# invalid expression terms in the layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to change several times the file but the only thing that I accomplishing every time is to add more invalid expressions

I am not able to see why now I have 6 invalid expression terms **';'** in the following code?

This my `_layout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Moran</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header ">
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                <span id="username">@User.Identity.Name</span>
                }
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Moran", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Galery">Galery</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Trips">Trips</a></li>
                    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {

                    <li><a asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    }

                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
            <p class="text-center text-danger">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Moran Ribadeo S.L.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <environment names="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/jScript/site.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Production,Staging">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/_app/site.js"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)

</body>

</html>
```

Could anybody advise?

Comment: Where are they occurring?

Comment: Your layout.cshtml looks good. Show the first view rendered by RenderBody ? I

Answer (score 0):

```
@model IEnumerable<Moran.Models.Trip>
@{ 
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>This is the welcome page</p>
        <a asp-controller="App" asp-action="trips" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">View trips</a>
    </div>
</div>
```